# Can I add a fuel filter to an Astra H 2005 Z16XEP

Tags: opel, astra, fuel-filter

I own an Opel Astra H 1.6 Caravan 2005 with a manual transmission (from Hamburg, Germany)

I'm driving it in a post-soviet with low fuel quality. As there is no fuel filter in the system (I checked several times, even "professionals" in my country are in  shock) I have to "wash injector" couple times a year.

Would just adding a simple filter to the fuel system be OK?

Comment: Yes it has a fuel filter built in to a pump. It cannot be replaced separately. Please publish some photos of what have you picked for a filter and how have you fit it in.

Answer (score 2):

It is a tank filter most likely and needs changing every 40k, see here : http://www.vauxhallownersnetwork.co.uk/index.php?threads/astra-1-6vvt-petrol-fuel-filter-location.278296/

As for adding a filter, yes you can, but make sure it and the fittings will be rated for the pressure in the supply line.

Comment: If you do add an inline filter you must disable or remove  the in tank filter.

Comment: @mikes why? nothing wrong with having two filters inline - worked well on the volvo I put a diesel engine in as one had a water trap as part of the filter assembly..

Comment: I agree with Solar ... shouldn't be an issue using both the intank and inline filters at the same time.

Comment: I assumed adding the second filter was to eliminate having to open the tank to replace the in-tank filter. With the in-tank filter in place, it will still require  cleaning or replacement every 40,000miles. The second filter is using the tank filter as a prefilter.