# Is it safe to add fuel filter(s) to a car

Tags: opel, astra, fuel-filter

I have an OPEL ASTRA H (A04) | 2004.01-2014.05 - 1.6 (L48) - 1598ccm 105pk  petrol car, which has the fuel filter built into the fuel pump, which is located in the tank.

The pump and fuel filter are not separated, and if you want to change the fuel filter, you have to change the pump. This is very expensive and complicated to do.

In order to protect the car from damage (which will eventually happen), I want to add an fuel filter to the fuel lines. I can then change the filter easily when needed.

I read [Can I add a fuel filter to an Astra H 2005 Z16XEP](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/48074/can-i-add-a-fuel-filter-to-an-astra-h-2005-z16xep), which states it is possible but I need to know the pressure for the supply line.

Is this safe to do, what fuel filter do I use, can the pressure in the lines change. Will the fuel pump have to pump harder and maybe get over worked with the added fuel filter ? Do I have to install it after or before the fuel pump or can I add two filters ?

Best regards,

Comment: I'm not sure you're right that you would have to replace the pump, I've never heard of a pump with a non-replaceable filter. You may have to remove the pump to get to the filter, but not replace the pump itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this safe to do?

Yes it is safe to do so.

> What fuel filter do I use?

Whatever you pick. We are not here to provide you shopping assistance, so I cannot answer that question for you.

> Can the pressure in the lines change.

Quite possibly yes. As the filters become increasingly clogged over time, first the flow will decrease, then as the demand for fuel goes up (due to the decreased flow), pressure will drop.

> Will the fuel pump have to pump harder and maybe get over worked with the added fuel filter ?

Yes. As the internal fuel filter becomes more and more clogged, the pump will be worked harder. This will ultimately cause it to fail sooner.

> Do I have to install it after or before the fuel pump or can I add two filters ?

I don't believe there's much of a way you can install it before the fuel pump, considering the fuel pump is inside the fuel tank and is collocated with the filter, so the only way you're going to get a filter on there is on the main fuel line after the fuel exits the fuel tank.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe to do, as long as you do it correctly ie don’t make any leaks.

For the pressure, you can either fit a pressure gauge to measure it or check the workshop manual - they usually specify the range of pressures and flow rates to expect when testing the pump.

If you install before the pump, how do you get there? This would mean taking the pump/filter assembly out and designing something to fit.

So you want to add two for a total of three filters - why? I don’t see much benefit to a third filter...

Adding one won’t make too much difference to the pump.

But if you want to prolong the life of the tank filter consider using a filter as the fuel goes into the tank.